# Ford Crown Victoria Interceptor v. Consumer Crown Victoria

Tags: ford, crown-victoria

Did the Interceptor version of the Crown Victoria come with a different ECU/Tune than the consumer version of the Crown Victoria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Crown_Victoria_Police_Interceptor#Comparison_with_standard_Crown_Victoria), there are many differences, but most of them are minor:

- Both use the same 4.6l SOHC V8 engine

The Police Interceptor (PI) has:

- An external oil cooler
- A slightly different tune which allows the engine to idle a slight bit higher (40rpm)
- Has more aggressive transmission shift points
- Transmission is built for harder, more aggressive shifts
- Different EGR control for 03+
- Most come with different rear end gear ratio (and different top speed) than stock
- Have a reinforced frame and body mounts and an optional limited slip rear differential
- Severe duty shock absorbers
- Stainless steel exhaust without resonators
- Most 04+ models have 200A alternators and a 75Ah battery

From what I'm seeing there isn't much there which will differentiate performance, but a bunch there which will help with the longevity of the vehicle, especially for handling the extreme abuse dealt by the Popo.